# Mars Rovers coding excercise, what is the use of Upper Right coordinates(5,5)?

Tags: c#

The mars Rover coding exercise can be read here https://github.com/microcosm/MarsRover

I completed this exercise. I see upper right coordinates mentioned as 5,5. And lower as 0,0. Why have they mentioned this? Is it a boundary?

I implemented a check in my code to not let the rover go beyond these two coordinates. I just assumed and did it. Was that the reason why upper coordinates where given? So -1,0 or 5,6 is wrong?

Comment: Sounds very simply like the old LOGO app.. from the 80s.. :) mmmmm

Answer (score 1):

One can only guess, but I reckon it's to look for devs like yourself that do bounds checking.  It's been about 4 years since I did that same test, and I don't remember checking for that condition, so maybe I failed :-)

Comment: or maybe who do more than what is needed(assumptions+implementations can be dangerous to stakeholders) :)